# VNC Client docker and port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, docker, vnc, vnc-viewer, docker-compose

I tried to access a `docker` image via port forwarding on a server with VNC Viewer.

I used port forwarding in a `docker-compose.yml` like this :

```
ports:
    - "5011:5901"
    - "5012:22/tcp"
    - "5014:2022/tcp"
```

However when I entered `my_server_address:5011` in `vncviewer` it failed.

Any clue why it is not working ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the error it throws at you? you should provide more information to unravel the problem

Comment: it shows connexion refused nothing else. That's why I don't really know what to do

Comment: find the solution you need to create a server inside the docker